# Running for statement in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to navigate to a folder, and delete all files that folder that isn't a certain file.

The command I have is as follows:

```
cd "bin\drivers" && for %i in (*.*) do if not %i == lol.exe del %i
```

however when I run this, the batch files opens and instantly closes, the same thing happens when its just the for statement by itself in the batch file.

I know the cd command works, and I know that the for command also works (only in cmd), when I open a cmd at the drivers folder and send the following command `for %i in (*.*) do if not %i == lol.exe del %i`, it will work as intended and delete every file that is not "lol.exe".

My question is how do I do I run this command in a batch file?

Comment: Add `/I` to the `if` part: `if /I not "%%i"=="lol.exe" ...`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the batch file you should add the sign percent `%`

```
cd "bin\drivers" && for %%i in (*.*) do if not %%i == lol.exe del %%i
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign double `%` when in a batch file. Also always wrap your variables in double quotes in order to ensure you do not match accidental whitespace:

```
@echo off
cd /d "bin\drivers" && for %%i in (*) do if not "%%~i"=="lol.exe" del "%%~i"
```

Using the conditional `&&` above is fine, it means it will not start the `for` loop if it could not successfully `cd` we simply `goto :eof` to ensure you do not run delete in the wrong directory.

```
@echo off
cd /d "bin\drivers" || goto :eof
for %%i in (*) do if not "%%~i"=="lol.exe" del "%%~i"
```

Secondly, you also do not need to use cd and can also use `pushd` and `popd` which stores the previous directory to `popd` to once done.

```
@echo off
pushd "bin\drivers" || goto :eof
for %%i in (*) do if not "%%~i"=="lol.exe" del "%%~i"
popd
```